# Problema para ejecutar pwsh (powershell 7) desde Windows PowerShell ISE

Tags: windows10, powershell, windows-server

por qué desde Windows PowerShell ISE al ejecutar **pwsh** se me queda congelado el terminal y no carga nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero el ejecutar el mismo comando desde Windows PowerShell si me carga powershell 7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento ya mire en las variables de entorno y todo luce bien, por favor su ayuda con este tema ya que debo es ejecutar pwsh desde powershell ISE, muchas gracias :D

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Oficialmente desde PowerShell 6 core y versiones posteriores, Microsoft ha dicho que Visual Studio Code es un editor multiplataforma, lo que facilita la escritura de scripts de PowerShell confiables. más info https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/powershell/scripting/whats-new/migrating-from-windows-powershell-51-to-powershell-7?view=powershell-7.3#improved-editing-experience-with-visual-studio-code